# Concatenation inside try catch

Tags: android

```
    try {
        final List<NetworkType> dataReceived = getData();
        int i = 0;
        //Array Iteration
        for(final NetworkType networkType : dataReceived) {
            i++;
            if (i > 3) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            } else {
                String mCell1CID = networkType.getCell1CID();
                String mCell1LAC = networkType.getCell1LAC();
                String mCell1MCC = networkType.getCell1MCC();
                String mCell1MNC = networkType.getCell1MNC();
                String mCell1CI = networkType.getCell1CI();
                String mCell1TAC = networkType.getCell1TAC();

                //API requestBody
                String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=AIzaSyA8NAA3dUpECFn2j6pdcQT3wgqUM98UZ2Q";
                String cellID = null;
                String locationAreaCode = null;
                if (mCell1CID.equals("") && mCell1LAC.equals("")) {
                    cellID = mCell1CI;
                    locationAreaCode = mCell1TAC;
                } else if (mCell1CI.equals("") && mCell1TAC.equals("")) {
                    cellID = mCell1CID;
                    locationAreaCode = mCell1LAC;
                } else {
                    Log.d("GeoL", "3");
                }
                String requestBody =
                        "{" +
                                "\"cellTowers\":[" +
                                "{" +
                                "\"cellId\"             :" + cellID + "," +
                                "\"locationAreaCode\"   :" + locationAreaCode + "," +
                                "\"mobileCountryCode\"  :" + "\"" + mCell1MCC + "\"" + "," +
                                "\"mobileNetworkCode\"  :" + "\"" + mCell1MNC + "\"" +
                                "}" +
                                "]" +
                                "}";

                // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
                JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                        (Request.Method.POST, url, requestBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject;
                                try {
                                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                                    JSONObject latitude = jsonObject.getJSONObject("location");
                                    String lat = latitude.getString("lat");
                                    String lng = latitude.getString("lng");
                                    String acc = jsonObject.getString("accuracy");
                                    if (!dataReceived.listIterator().hasNext()){
                                        String print;
                                        print = String.format("%s%s", print, print(lat.toString(), lng.toString(), acc.toString()));
                                        writeToFile(print, getApplicationContext());
                                    } else {
                                        String print;
                                        print = String.format("%s%s,", print, print(lat.toString(), lng.toString(), acc.toString()));
                                        writeToFile(print, getApplicationContext());
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Log.e("Response", "error" + error.toString());
                            }
                        });
                queue.add(jsObjRequest);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I need to concat the received value to the print variable. 
But this the error which i receive
print needs to be initialized is what I receive.
also if declared outside the try/catch block it requires it to be final.
What to do?

Comment: Paste your entire code.

Comment: pasted, kindly recheck

Comment: Okay, so where's the loop inside that function? What you've defined is a callback. What should `print` contain before invocation? What is its purpose?

Comment: one print is the variable, the other one is method. I want to append all strings received in the loop to the print variable, which should be formatted according to print method.

Comment: Okay, in that case you should take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896030/how-do-i-use-a-variable-outside-the-onresponse-in-android). 
Also, it makes no sense to keep redeclaring the variable if you want to append to it each time.

Comment: I cannot use it outside the onResponse, coz the data received needs to be recorded each time the loop is iterated. so i think this also wont help. Thanks though :)

Comment: So that's the thing. You want to append it at each iteration. But how can you? `print` is a local variable to the callback function and therefore has _no idea_ it is being called inside a loop. So what you want is a variable that is local, but also retains information each time it is called. That is not possible.

Comment: so is there any other way with which i can get this done

Comment: The link I pasted shows how to access this variable from outside the function, so you can concatenate each time without having to redeclare it. Declare `print` ONCE outside the loop, then use it.

Answer (score 0):

You are providing a value that is not initialized to the `String.format`

You need to initialize the variable "print" with what you want to be used in the String.format (for example an empty String) :

`String print= ""`

Or use String Builder:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

stringBuilder.append("1");
stringBuilder.append("2");

String finalString = stringBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: i need to append each value received in the loop. so initializing it to null would not work

Comment: I initialized it with an empty string , not null.

Comment: Also since you updated the question, i suggest using moshi or Gson for easily creating and reading json data.

Comment: already using gson but for some other json file. as far as initializing is concerned, either of the initializations, the null or an empty string wont work because the value of the variable would be refreshed each time the loop is iterated. Therefore null or empty string wont work. Also initialiazing it outside the loop then asks me to declare it final. Which again is not the solution.

Comment: I added another solution if your goal is to just concatenate them.

Comment: i tried stringbuilder as well, but it didnt work because of the the data I receive and parameters in the print method. I did change them but how to change data received from api  to stringbuilder.

Comment: just pass whatever you are appending to the string builder , e.g. `print(lat.toString(), lng.toString(), acc.toString())`

Answer (score 0):

just use `String print = null;` when you declare `print`

Comment: i need to append each value received in the loop. so initializing it to null would not work

Comment: then just declare and initialize it outside loop and use it to append values inside loop
'String print = null;
for(...){  print = print + "some value"; }'

Comment: then it asks to declare it final